# Does a queued job in Laravel get stopped if deleted from database?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-queue

I am trying to implement a feature when a user deletes their account, it activates a job that queues in a week, but the user is allowed to cancel this queue if they decide to keep their account. However, I noticed when I deleted the job from the database, the job didn't activate. Is this the right way to cancel the queued job?

I am using the database option for my **QUEUE_CONNECTION=database** in my .env file. I also have a jobs table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all failed jobs from database use:

```
php artisan queue:flush
```

To remove a failed job from database use:

```
php artisan queue:forget your_failed_job_uid
```

To remove all jobs from database use:

```
php artisan queue:clear
```

As a note:
your system will deal with queues depend on queue configuration like delayed job or a failed job retried 3 times and after each one there is a delay.

Comment: Interesting I am going to try to implement that command for my controller. Thanks!

Comment: Oh I was wondering how would I cancel a job that hasn't failed and is scheduled to activate later.

Comment: DB::table('jobs')->where('id','your job id')->delete(); You could create a custom artisan command accept job id as an argument ;

Comment: Thanks! This was really helpful! I implemented something similar where I would store user and job id in a separate table. If user wants to cancel the job call a command similar to yours.